# InstallShield Express - create and start LocalDb instance during install

Tags: wpf, installshield, localdb, sql-server-2012-localdb

I'm using InstallShield Express in a Visual Studio 2015 WPF solution that uses LocalDb. What is the best way to get the InstallShield installer to create and start a LocalDb instance?

I was thinking a batch file or some way for it to execute the "SqlLocalDb create InstanceName"  and "SqlLocalDb start InstanceName" commands, but how do you get InstallShield to run those commands?

Thanks!